# Javascript Paypal slider string suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, slider

I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/y8owze31/6/. I need to be able to apply a suffix to the string via a variable. The way I am doing it now is very primitive. What I mean is

```
$(function() {
var1 = "suffix"
$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 1,
  max: 50,
  value: 25,
  slide: function( event,ui, string) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value + "suffix" );
      $( "#amt_id" ).val( ui.value );
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work the way I would like it to and just tries to calculate with the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you situation, you need to define your value type in:

```
$( "#amount" ).val( ui.value + "suffix" );
```

and in:

```
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

javascript does not know which type of data you enter. You should define such as respectively:

```
$( "#amount" ).val( "" + ui.value + "suffix" );
```

and

```
$( "#amount" ).val("" + $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) + "suffix" );
```

See, you add some quotation mark in where your value is you simply edit your variable as a string value.

Cheers!

And here is [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Herger/y8owze31/8/)